# Register Ecore meta-model programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I use a transformation engine to create an Ecore meta-model at runtime and I wonder how we can register that meta-model with EMF so that it can recognize the meta-model?

Answer (score 17):

If you have the code generated by your metamodel:

```java
resourceSet.getPackageRegistry()
  .put(org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.GenModelPackage.eINSTANCE.getNsURI()
     , org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.genmodel.GenModelPackage.eINSTANCE);
```

(here for the "genmodel" metamodel)

If you only have the `.ecore` file:

```java
// register globally the Ecore Resource Factory to the ".ecore" extension
// weird that we need to do this, but well...
Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.getExtensionToFactoryMap().put(
    "ecore", new EcoreResourceFactoryImpl());

ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSetImpl();
// enable extended metadata
final ExtendedMetaData extendedMetaData = new BasicExtendedMetaData(rs.getPackageRegistry());
rs.getLoadOptions().put(XMLResource.OPTION_EXTENDED_META_DATA,
    extendedMetaData);

Resource r = rs.getResource(uriOfYourModel, true);
EObject eObject = r.getContents().get(0);
if (eObject instanceof EPackage) {
    EPackage p = (EPackage)eObject;
    rs.getPackageRegistry().put(p.getNsURI(), p);
}
```

You can find a bit more about this code [here](https://github.com/eclipse/acceleo/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.acceleo.common/src/org/eclipse/acceleo/common/internal/utils/AcceleoPackageRegistry.java) with the method named `registerEcorePackages()`, used to register `.ecore` file in the workspace (with their workspace fullpath) in our custom package registry. If you want to register your metamodel in EMF global package registry, replace `resourceSet.getPackageRegistry()` by `EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE`.

Comment: SUPERB ANSWER!!!!!! Thanks a lot Stephane ! Can't thank you enough..... The "ecore file" technique is what I'm looking for!

Comment: Hi, awesome thank you! I had to modify the code a bit for it to work. Please see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify the code from @sbegaudeau a bit for it to work:

Replace

`rs.getPackageRegistry().put(p.getNsURI(), p);`

with

`EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE.put(p.getNsURI(), p);`

Also, somehow I cannot register the .ecore type. Had to use "*": `Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE.
getExtensionToFactoryMap().put("*", new EcoreResourceFactoryImpl());`